# Javascript buffer inconsistency when converting between binary and base64

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a png between binary and base64 due to communication with the server.  However, when I use buffer there is inconsistency between directly reading the file in base64 versus reading the file in binary then converting to base64.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var data1 = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('test.png')).toString();
data1 = Buffer.from(data1).toString('base64');
var data2 = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('test.png')).toString('base64');
data1 == data2; //false
```

What could be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: Strange, the only thing I can think is putting data1 into a buffer includes the string terminator.

Comment: Neither of those is reading the file directly in base64?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the problem.  As someone else mentioned, the default encoding is utf-8.  However, it seems utf-8 causes some information loss so it's impossible to convert it back to base64.  Therefore, one only has to specify the encoding for this to work.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var data1 = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('test.png')).toString('binary');
data1 = Buffer.from(data1,'binary').toString('base64');
var data2 = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('test.png')).toString('base64');
data1 == data2; //true
```

However, I'm curious why utf-8 would causes this problem and it would be great if someone would give me a hand.

Comment: Ah I missed the `from(data, encoding)`... Good to know.